# What compression options does 7Zip use when you add files with a drag-drop?

Tags: compression, zip, 7-zip, archiving

When you create an archive with 7Zip, you get a dialog showing you a bunch of compression options.  However when you drag-drop some files into an already-open archive in a 7Zip window, you just get a "Confirm file copy" dialog which, when you click Yes, just adds the files to the archive.  What compression settings does it use when doing this and how can they be changed?

Comment: I assume same compression algorithm it is already using for the existing archive.

Comment: To change the compression scheme, 1. Unpack all files in the archive. 2. Select all in 7-Zip. 3. Add to a new compressed archive, whether Zip, 7z or something else. You can't convert one compression method to another.